# Implicit integer conversion in C99 vs static code checker

Tags: integer, c99, implicit-conversion, literals, suffix

I am using something like the following in my C99 code:

```
 uint64_t x = 1000ULL * (5U * 1000U);
```

I assumed `U` always means `unsigned int`.

My static code checker now complains about implicit type conversion here, which is correct. However it does not complain about `unsigned long long` vs `unsigned int`. It complains about `unsigned char` vs `unsigned short` instead.

So my questions is: 
Can those literals above be interpreted as something other (especially smaller) than `unsigned long long` and `unsigned int` in C99?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in C99 or any other version of the C standard constants with th a `U` suffix always are unsigned and the number of `L` gives you the rank `int`, `long` or `long long`.